# Merge git branches using gear wheel principle based on commit time

Tags: git

I have two branches like

[image]

As you see, the commits comes in chronologic order in those branches.

How do I merge them so that the resulting branch will cherry pick commit by commit from those branches, selecting the next in chronologic order in a "gear wheel" fashion like

[image]

Comment: Why is the chronological output desired? What do those branches actually represent? If it's two simultaneous tracks of work, for example, wouldn't one then the other be a more logical result?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it was a near thing. say [git help cherrypick](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=git+help+cherrypick) and you'll see the docs, your question is a near-exact match for one of the examples. "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: This _isn't_ a forum, and you've had one single downvote which is hardly _"aggressive"_. That said git is a pretty widely used tool, the odds of asking something nobody ever thought of before and that therefore _couldn't_ be found through research are pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout $(git merge-base branch1 branch2)
git rev-list --reverse --no-merges --date-order branch1...branch2 \
| git cherry-pick --stdin
```

will do it if "the next in chronologic order" is the important part, otherwise you need to generate two lists and use your favorite text-munging tool to splice the two into the arbitrary interleave order to feed them to cherrypick.